# num_rows returning 0 on a login form

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I know this has been discussed but the problem is slightly confusing. I am using mysqli prepared statements, but I also tried with raw queries. num_rows is always 0, and I have no Idea why. As a result of this, the login form is a failure.
Below is the php code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

session_start();
if(isset($_POST["userLogin"])){
$email = ($_POST["userEmail"]);
$password =($_POST["userPassword"]);
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
'customer_email'=? AND 'customer_password' =?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
$stmt->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION["user"] = $row["customer_id"];
$_SESSION["email"] = $row["customer_email"];

echo "logged in";

} else {
echo "Email / password combination incorrect";
}
}
?>
```

This is the javascript code below.

```
$("#login").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var email = $("#email").val();
var pass = $("#password").val();
$.ajax({
url :"login.php",
method: "POST",
data    :   {userLogin:1,userEmail:email,userPassword:pass},
success :function(data){
alert(data);

}
})
})
```

Following is the HTML

```
<label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
<input type ="email" class ="form-control" id="email" required/>
<label for="email">Password</label>
<input type ="password" class ="form-control" id="password" required/>
<p><br/></p>
<a href="#" style="color:white; list-style:none;">Forgotten 
Password</a><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
style="float:right;" id="login" value="Login">
```

The concerned database looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO `customers` (`customer_id`, `customer_name`, 
`customer_email`, `customer_pass`, `customer_country`, 
`customer_city`, `customer_address`, `customer_zipcode`)
```

Registration works just fine and there are no other problems. I have had the mysql num_rows return 0 before and storing the result fixed the problem. However, this time it is way too complicated. I have been trying to debug for hours and not a thing. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried replacing affected row with num rows, and also without fetching. Same problem. Mysql thinks I have 0 rows although i have quite a lot! I donno how to fix this but this is very upsetting. I have been trying for over 24 hours now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you using ``num_rows``? I see ``affected_rows`` which according to [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) **Returns the number of rows affected by INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query.** and your doing a ``SELECT``

Comment: I have tried with both num rows and affected rows and they both return 0. I used affected rows for a search function for this web app and it worked fine.

Comment: The jquery code is problematic. I tried with php and it works. Can I get some insight what Im doing wrong with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this old question. It appears you are using quotes (') around your field/column names. As far as I know, and the documentation agrees, mySQL doesnt support that. You have to use one if the following:

- nothing, example: select field1 from table1
- backticks, example: select `field1` from table1
- double quotes, example: select "field1" from table1

The last one only applies if ANSI_QUOTES is enabled.

Now I havent tried your code, but the use of the quotes makes your query compare two strings, not a field/column to a string. Your query

'customer_email'=?

literary means: compare the text customer_email to the value of the bound parameter. Unless the entered username/email in the form IS customer_email, it will never match. Same for the password.